# Twitter Typeahead works only with data-source

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

Twitter Bootstrap data-source only working. No Javascript working :(

I tried many tutorial but all are not working.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#lookup_input').typeahead({                                
  name: 'Search',                                                          
  prefetch: 'data.json',
  limit: 10                                                                   
});                                                
</script>
```

any simple typeahead example?

Comment: Typeahead was removed from bootstrap 3. Use: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/. If your path on the prefetch is incorrect, it won't work.

Comment: file exists . i tried there prefetch . Noting working. :( so i added old typeahead :) This is code from Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I have no idea how your setting up your page, where code is loaded, whether you've checked the path and trouble shooted with developer tools. Load up a .json file on your server, chmod to 644, try to load it directly in browser, see what happens. http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/1004312